# JavaScript error: cannot read property of undefined "this"?

Tags: javascript, this, keyboard-events, addeventlistener

I want to convert to uppercase what the user is typing in the text field of a html form:

```
<input type="text" id="inputword" name="inputword">
```

I've added an event listener to that input element on the keyup event:

```
document.getElementById("inputword").addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
```

And this is the function that is called when the "keyup" event is triggered

```
function myFunction() {
    // Convert to uppercase on keyup event                                                  
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();                                 
}
```

This works. When the user types a character, it is shown in uppercase on the input text field (using **this.value** inside the function

Now, I would like to pass a parameter to the function. As far as I understood, to pass parameters when using the 
**addEventListener()** method, an "anonymous function" is required.

I'm trying to pass a String to the function in this way:

```
document.getElementById("inputword").addEventListener("keyup", function() {      
        myFunction("TEST");                                                     
});  

function myFunction(myString) {  
    // Convert to uppercase on keyup event                                                 
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();                             
    ... // do other things                     
}
```

But now, when I type something on the text field, I get the following error:

```
myscript.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined(…)
```

It seems that "**this.value**" is not defined anymore after using an "anonymous function" when registering the event. Is there a way to access "**this**" inside my function?

My javascript code is in an external file included at the end of the html body:

```
   <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>                                    
</body>
```

Comment: Every new function call creates a new scope with a new `this`

Comment: Use: myFunction(this, "TEST"); and then: function myFunction(field, myString) { field.value = field.value.toUpperCase(); }